# Split HL7-segments into awk records and extract specific values into csv-file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a script that runs through a set of HL7-files. From this script I'm trying to extract specific values from different segments of each file (MSH.7, PID.3, ORC.15 and OBR.46). The file looks like the example below (each file contains one long single line):

```
MSH|^~\&|SYSTEM|SENDER|RECEIVER|TST001^5790000192137^EAN|20230420170201.161+0100||OMG^O19^OMG_O19|OMGFPPQE54|P^T|2.5.1|||AL|AL||UNICODE UTF-8^MPID|||0101701111^^^&2.16.840.1.113883.3.4208.100.2&ISO||*********^*******||********|*|||************^^*****^^****^***^^^***||^***^**^^^^^^^^^********^MPD1|||^^^^^YNR^^^^12345^MAL1|1|OA^MORC|NW|14052154446^SENDER||1234567891012999^SENDER||||||||12345^Petersen^Peter C.^^^^^^YNR|||20230420154700||||||Lægehuset^^^^^YNR^^^^12345^MTQ1|||||||||R^MOBR||||UNSPECIFIED^Waiting visitation^99IMG|||||||||||||||||||||||||||^CT af thorax Gruppe 3\X0A\|||||||||||||||8001047^X-Ray Department^99SKS^MOBX||CE|OBS_010034^^99IMG||^.||||||O
```

I'm able to extract single values using below:

```
grep -Po "^MSH.*(?=PID)" | awk -F'|' '{ print $7 }'
```

But I'd like to be able to run through each file and extract values from each segment individually and add these values to a csv-file. A combination of the following that outputs individual values seperated with a comma to a csv-file:

```
grep -Po "^MSH.*(?=PID)" | awk -F'|' '{ print $7 }'
grep -Po "PID.*(?=PD1)" | awk -F'|' '{ print $7 }'
grep -Po "ORC.*(?=TQ1)" | awk -F'|' '{ print $7 }'
grep -Po "OBR.*(?=OBX)" | awk -F'|' '{ print $7 }'
```

I've tried using `RS="MSH|PID|ORC|OBR"`, but have not been able to find a working solution. Anyone with a nice solution to this?

Expected output (hope this makes sense):

```
{MSH.7},{PID.3},{ORC.15},{OBR.46} // file 1 = 20230420170201.161+0100, 0101701111^^^&2.16.840.1.113883.3.4208.100.2&ISO, 20230420154700, 8001047^X-Ray Department^99SKS^MOBX
{MSH.7},{PID.3},{ORC.15},{OBR.46} // file 2
{MSH.7},{PID.3},{ORC.15},{OBR.46} // file 3
...
{MSH.7},{PID.3},{ORC.15},{OBR.46} // file n
```

Kind regards,
Thomas

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: @cyrus Expected output added to the question.

Comment: please update the expected output with *actual* values corresponding to the sample input you've provided;  the current set of expected output does not make sense ... *1)* based on the current expected output it looks like `print "{MSH.7},{PID.3},{ORC.15},{OBR.46}"` should be sufficient for this task since you're stating all files should have the same (static) output, *2)* I don't see anything in the input that matches `MSH.7`, `PID.3`, `ORC.15` nor `OBR.46` and *3)* when I run you 1st `grep|awk` snippet I get `20230420170201.161+0100` but I don't see this anywhere in your expected output

Comment: Is there any logic to getting values like 7? Do you use regex only? I found a page [like this](https://www.interfaceware.com/hl7-message-structure#:~:text=HL7%20Messages%20are%20used%20to,require%20some%20effort%20to%20interpret.) Do you use that to get those values?

Comment: I appreciate that you added your expected output, and given that you are only looking for field `$7`, do we really need such a gigantic input string?  Consider editing the data to include only the needed pieces used by your extraction logic. Hopefully it will not require carefully scrolling to the right (-;! Good luck.

Comment: @shelter I don't control the data-files, so it's not an option.

Comment: Yes, but we don't need to see all of that data to help you solve the logic and syntax problems you may be having. Read about [mcve] and think about how you can reduce what we have to wade thru to understand the basic problem. Good luck.

Comment: Noticed there are literal chars `^` and `M`, but there are also `^S,^E,^O,^J` and lots of free standing `^` chars, maybe they are the field seperators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = "|"
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ "MSH") {
            printf "%s, ", $(i + 6)
        } else if ($i ~ "PID") {
            printf "%s, ", $(i + 3)
        } else if ($i ~ "ORC") {
            printf "%s, ", $(i + 15)
        } else if ($i ~ "OBR") {
            printf "%s", $(i + 46)
        }
    }
    printf " // %s\n", FILENAME
}' file*
20230420170201.161+0100, 0101701111^^^&2.16.840.1.113883.3.4208.100.2&ISO, 20230420154700, 8001047^Alb Røntgen Ambulatorium^99SKS^MOBX // file1.txt
```

Comment: This looks very promising, thx :)  I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Works.  Sorry for the confusing data-format. That's HL7.

Comment: I had to google HL7, but it absolutely makes sense why your example looks so complicated @Bohsen (that's just how HL7 records look). It's a little 'tricky' to work with this type of data though (e.g. what if there is a pipe character within a field?), so have you considered other languages? E.g. https://python-hl7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Regardless, I'm glad you solved your problem.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Googling HL7, was actually how I started my journey in HL7 :)
Regarding python, I'd need python to be installed, which our security team would never allow. So your `awk` solution (which is much cooler IMO) fits perfectly, as long as I'm only allowed ssh-access to the built-in linux tools.